# Improving the code that parses a Text File

Tags: java, file, parsing, file-io

Text File(First three lines are simple to read, next three lines starts with p)

```
ThreadSize:2
ExistingRange:1-1000
NewRange:5000-10000
p:55 - AutoRefreshStoreCategories  Data:Previous    UserLogged:true    Attribute:1    Attribute:16      Attribute:2060  
p:25 - CrossPromoEditItemRule      Data:New         UserLogged:false     Attribute:1      Attribute:10107   Attribute:10108
p:20 - CrossPromoManageRules       Data:Previous    UserLogged:true      Attribute:1      Attribute:10107   Attribute:10108
```

Below is the code I wrote to parse the above file and after parsing it I am setting the corresponding values using its Setter. I just wanted to know whether I can improve this code more in terms of parsing and other things also by using other way like using RegEx? My main goal is to parse it and set the corresponding values. Any feedback or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
private List<Command> commands;
private static int noOfThreads = 3;
private static int startRange = 1;
private static int endRange = 1000;
private static int newStartRange = 5000;
private static int newEndRange = 10000;
private BufferedReader br = null;
private String sCurrentLine = null;
private int distributeRange = 100;
private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
private String commandName;
private static String data;
private static boolean userLogged;
private static List<Integer> attributeID =  new ArrayList<Integer>();

    try {
        // Initialize the system
        commands = new LinkedList<Command>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("S:\\Testing\\Test1.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(sCurrentLine.contains("ThreadSize")) {
                noOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split(":")[1]);
            } else if(sCurrentLine.contains("ExistingRange")) {
                startRange = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split(":")[1].split("-")[0]);
                endRange = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split(":")[1].split("-")[1]);
            } else if(sCurrentLine.contains("NewRange")) {
                newStartRange = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split(":")[1].split("-")[0]);
                newEndRange = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split(":")[1].split("-")[1]);
            } else {
                allLines.add(Arrays.asList(sCurrentLine.split("\\s+")));
                String key = sCurrentLine.split("-")[0].split(":")[1].trim();
                String value = sCurrentLine.split("-")[1].trim();
                values = Arrays.asList(sCurrentLine.split("-")[1].trim().split("\\s+"));
                for(String s : values) {
                    if(s.contains("Data:")) {
                        data = s.split(":")[1];
                    } else if(s.contains("UserLogged:")) {
                        userLogged = Boolean.parseBoolean(s.split(":")[1]);
                    } else if(s.contains("Attribute:")) {
                        attributeID.add(Integer.parseInt(s.split(":")[1]));
                    } else {
                        commandName = s;
                    }
                }

                Command command = new Command();
                command.setName(commandName); 
                command.setExecutionPercentage(Double.parseDouble(key));
                command.setAttributeID(attributeID);
                command.setDataCriteria(data);
                command.setUserLogging(userLogged);
                commands.add(command);

            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: This is not a question... but you could use regexp for last 3 lines to retrive data. Or even you can create class that have setters: "set..." and set the values via reflection.

Comment: Can you give me any example for regular expression with my TextFile. That will be of great help.

Comment: First code improvements: stop using static variables like this. I would suggest that all the *data* variables should be instance variables, and all the *temporary* variables (the reader etc) should be local to the method which populates the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer a comment:

```
p:55 - AutoRefreshStoreCategories  Data:Previous    UserLogged:true    Attribute:1    Attribute:16      Attribute:2060
```

to parse above with regex (and 3 times `Attribute:`):

```
String parseLine = "p:55 - AutoRefreshStoreCategories  Data:Previous    UserLogged:true    Attribute:1    Attribute:16      Attribute:2060";
    Matcher m = Pattern
            .compile(
                    "p:(\\d+)\\s-\\s(.*?)\\s+Data:(.*?)\\s+UserLogged:(.*?)\\s+Attribute:(\\d+)\\s+Attribute:(\\d+)\\s+Attribute:(\\d+)")
            .matcher(parseLine);
    if(m.find()) {
        int p = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        String method = m.group(2);
        String data = m.group(3);
        boolean userLogged = Boolean.valueOf(m.group(4));
        int at1 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(5));
        int at2 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(6));
        int at3 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(7));
        System.out.println(p + " " + method + " " + data + " " + userLogged + " " + at1 + " " + at2 + " "
                + at3);
    }
```

**EDIT** looking at your comment you still can use regex:

```
String parseLine = "p:55 - AutoRefreshStoreCategories  Data:Previous    UserLogged:true    "
            + "Attribute:1    Attribute:16      Attribute:2060";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("p:(\\d+)\\s-\\s(.*?)\\s+Data:(.*?)\\s+UserLogged:(.*?)").matcher(
            parseLine);
    if(m.find()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); ++i) {
            System.out.println(m.group(i + 1));
        }
    }

    Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("Attribute:(\\d+)").matcher(parseLine);
    while(m2.find()) {
        System.out.println("Attribute matched: " + m2.group(1));
    }
```

But that depends if thre is no `Attribute:` names before "real" attributes (for example as method name - after `p`)

Comment: Thanks for an example. But I think you are assuming Attribute will always be three in this case. It can be more than three. So using RegEx approach in that case will be helpful as upfront we will not be aware of how many attributes are there. So in that case my code will be better right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should know what exactly you're expecting while using RegEx. http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/ should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. It has some helper methods to read text files

Answer (score 0):

I would turn this inside out. Presently you are:

1. Scanning the line for a keyword: the entire line if it isn't found, which is the usual case as you have a number of keywords to process and they won't all be present on every line.
2. Scanning the entire line again for ':' and splitting it on all occurrences
3. Mostly parsing the part after ':' as an integer, or occasionally as a range.

So several complete scans of each line. Unless the file has zillions of lines this isn't a concern in itself but it demonstrates that you have got the processing back to front.